# Trigger a button click that is inside a user control from a windows form in c#

Tags: c#, .net, mouseevent

I'm developing an application in c# .net framework and I have a user control not developed by me that contains various buttons that when clicked show different kind of data and statistics (let's call it ucDataShow).

Such user control is in a different tab with respect to the main tab of my program (i'm talking about  TabControl)

I'd like to create a button in my application that when clicked changes tab and shows the appropriate kind of data by simulating the click of the appropriate button of ucDataShow

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: It depends whether the controls and event handlers in the user control are private or public. If they are private you will have to resort to [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) hacks. Since we do not have enough information about this user control, we cannot give you better answers.

Answer (score 0):

you can change tabpage of tabcontrol like this:
tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabControl1.TabPages[n];

but i think it is not possible to raise click event of button which is on ucDataShow control.